# How to update Pandas dataframe with a new column using values from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can I use Pandas to update / combine / merge a dataframe (df1) with values from another dataframe (df2) where df1 has a new column (col3) with values from df2.col2? In other words, df1 is the current month values and I would like df1 to also have a column from df2 which is last month's values.

Any insights on this is appreciated; thank you SO.

df1:

| key | date | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | feb-01 | df1_val01 | df1_val02 |
| key2 | feb-01 | df1_val11 | df1_val12 |

df2:

| key | date | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | jan-01 | df2_val01 | df2_val02 |
| key2 | jan-01 | df2_val11 | df2_val12 |

desired df:

| key | date | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | feb-01 | df1_val01 | df1_val02 | df2_val01 |
| key2 | feb-01 | df1_val11 | df1_val12 | df2_val12 |

Comment: Just merge the two. `pd.merge(df1, df2[['key', 'col1']].rename(columns={'col1':'col3'}), on='key', how='inner')`

Answer (score 0):

Merging, joining, concatenating, dataframes can be tricky. One of the simplest ways I've found is to make the shared "key" column into an index. Rename the column (to "col3" in your case) and join on the "key" index column.

In your case, it would look like:

```
right_df = df_1[["key", "col2"]].set_index("key")
right_df = right_df.rename(columns={"col2": "col3"})
new_df = df2.join(right_df, on="key")
```

(I didn't test this code. This is from memory. Let me know if it fails miserably and I'll see if I can fix it.)